# Font ligatures weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, css

My headings have negative `letter-spacing` but I still want the typefaces ligatures to work ("ffi", "ffl", "ffj", "fi", "fl", "fj", "ff"). I'm selecting these characters using JS, wrapping them in a `span` and setting `letter-spacing` to zero and hence the ligatures work. But there is a weird behaviour. The ligatures work, but if there is a mix of ligatures in the same element, some no longer work. See below. In the first example the ffi ligature doesn't work, but in the second example it does. What's going on?

UPDATE
On closer look if there is more than one glyph in an element, the browser is choosing the "fi" glyph over the "ffi" glyph. Weird!

```js
// add 'glyph' class to ligatures

let ligatures = ["ffi", "ffl", "ffj", "fi", "fl", "fj", "ff"];
// select ligatures within h1 element. Other elements can be added by seperating them with a comma
highlightLigatures(document.querySelectorAll("h1"), ligatures);

function highlightLigatures(elements, substrings) {
  elements.forEach((el) => {
    highlightText(el, substrings, "glyph");
  });
}

function highlightText(el, substrings, classNames = "glyph") {
  substrings.forEach((substring) => {
    let regex = new RegExp(`(${substring})`, "gi");
    el.childNodes.forEach((childNode) => {
      if (childNode.nodeValue && regex.test(childNode.nodeValue)) {
        childNode.parentNode.innerHTML = childNode.parentNode.innerHTML.replace(
          regex,
          `<span class="${classNames}">${substring}</span>`
        );
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-family: georgia;
  font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;
  font-weight: 400
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: -0.08em;
}

.glyph {
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cormorant+Garamond&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<h1>Office (the ffi ligature is not working) Often Oficial Offset</h1>
<h1>Office (the ffi ligature is working)</h1>
```

Comment: The "ff"s in your stack snippet look identical to me (joined, and the first `f` is slightly shorter than the second). In what way are you seeing the ligature "not work"?

Comment: It's the obvious comment and a frame challenge, but: Negative letter spacing is hard on readability. Do you really *need* negative letter spacing? Genuine question, not snark. :-)

Comment: Maybe you're better off modifying the font-face?

Comment: The first ffi ligature doesn't work, but in the second example it does (the three letters are joined into a single glyph)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder It's common in typography to set headings with tighter tracking.

Comment: @mb21 I've tried this on a number of different fonts from Google Adobe and FontStand and get the same issue.

Comment: I meant to modify the font file and use a different version of it for the titles instead of using negative letter-spacing. Or you could use a [variable font](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_fonts/Variable_fonts_guide) :)

Comment: _"the browser is choosing the "fi" glyph over the "ffi" glyph"_ - you end up wrapping `ffi` as `<span class="glyph">f<span class="glyph">fi</span></span>`, because you code replaces the `ffi` to `<span class="glyph">ffi</span>` first, and then goes on to find `fi` in that again later on. You'll have to find a way of not replacing "partial" ligatures in already replaced "broader" ligatures any more.

Comment: @CBroe yeah you're right. There is a span inside the span. But strangely the ffi ligature works, if it is the only ligature in the element.

Comment: @CBroe I've tried reordering the JS "let ligatures = ["fi", "fl", "fj", "ff", "ffi", "ffl", "ffj"];" but that just makes things worse. The browser finds "fi" and wraps it in a span, so that it can then no longer find the "ffi" characters.

Comment: I'm having a hard time telling what the difference between "working" and "not working" is supposed to be to begin with, in your given example.

Comment: @CBroe Working = the three "ffi" characters being replaced by the typefaces "ffi" ligature (the three characters are joined into 'one' ligature or character. Not working = only the "fi" characters being replaced by the typefaces specially designed "fi" ligature.

Comment: I've updated the code snippet labelling what is and isn't working

Comment: Yes, I'm aware what ligatures are - I'm just not seeing _any_ discernible difference between _all_ occurrences of `ffi` in the given example.

Comment: Interesting... In Safari, in the first example, the ffi characters are not joined. But in the second, working example, the f and the f are joined and the second f is joined to the i by the dot of the i. What browser are you using? Perhaps it is a browser thing?

Comment: Firefox or Chromium, both on a Mac. The `ffi` characters are joined in the first example as well in those.

Comment: Seems to be a Safari issue. I've just checked on my Mac in Chrome and Firefox and the ffi characters are joined in both examples (despite the span inside a span)

Comment: Avoiding those nested spans would require digging a bit deeper into that replacement logic, finding a way to determine that the found match was inside of such a `.glyph` element already ... Which I am not having much luck with r/n, but as a workaround, `el.querySelectorAll('.glyph').forEach((e => e.innerHTML = e.innerText))` inserted at the very end of your `highlightText` function, appears to do the job at least.

Comment: Wow, thanks for putting so much into this. Unfortunately I don't know anything about JavaScript so don't have the faintest idea where to put that code. Could you show me in an answer to my post?

Comment: Not sure if my workaround suggestion justifies giving a _real_ answer here, but you can see it in action in this fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/1687kh9q/ It basically replaces the HTML content of each `.glyph` element with its text content again - meaning in cases where you have them _nested_ into each other, manipulating the "outer" one, will _remove_ the inner. (And since these elements _can_ only contain text, that should be harmless to apply.) Safari's problem appears to be indeed the "division" over multiple elements.

Comment: @CBroe wow! Thank you ever so much. On first glance that looks great. I'll have to revisit this tomorrow. Thank you again

Comment: @CBroe works perfectly. Why are you reticent about calling this a 'real' answer? Is there a potential issue I should be aware of? Thanks again

Comment: @user2991837 because it fixes the problem only by removing superfluous `.glyph` elements afterwards, instead of preventing their creation in the first place :-) But the logic to do the latter would probably be quite a bit more complex, so if this workaround achieves what you require to your satisfaction, I'm happy to add it as a "real" answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code ends up wrapping `ffi` as `<span class="glyph">f<span class="glyph">fi</span></span>`, because it replaces the `ffi` to `<span class="glyph">ffi</span>` first, and then goes on to find `fi` in that again later on. And apparently Safari has a problem recognizing such combinations of characters that would justify showing the ligature version, when they are distributed across multiple elements.

Trying to modify the logic to recognize that the found text is inside a `.glyph` element already, would probably be a bit more complex matter - so as an easier workaround, we can replace the superfluous elements with their mere text content again, using

```
el.querySelectorAll('.glyph').forEach((e => e.innerHTML = e.innerText));
```

after the replacements are all done.